# how to set the order of row by drag and drop in python django with jquery and save that order in the database

Tags: python, jquery, django

want to change the row by drag and drop and also save the order in the database accordingly. i have used the javascript .sortable function and used Jquery to sort it but it is,nt saving the order. i want to change and save both.

```
<table class="table" id="labourTable">

  <thead>

    <tr>

      <th></th>

      <th>Name</th>

      <th>L Group</th>

      <th>C Group</th>

      <th>Order</th>

      <th>Image Source</th>

      <th>Data Source</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>
```

**'show data of labor in tablerow'**

```
{% for labor in labours %}
  <tr>

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="{{ labour.id }}" /></td>

    <td><a href="{% url 'mapport.laps.lbours.one' map.id labour.i:)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out JQuery UI sortable ordering: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

That way you can sort your rows. To store the order in the database you should have to add an order positive integer field in the model you want to order, send the row orders through the post method to the view and save the rows there asigning their order `row_model_instance.order`.

Comment: can yo please share some.. i am totally lost now